# Calculating biggest possible height of document

Tags: javascript, html

I encountered a problem while writing a website. In brief, I wanted to calculate the biggest possible height of the document (essentially the window.innerHeight if the window was full screen.). I used this simple line of code to calculate that in such a way so that it works in whichever size your window is.

```
window.screen.height - (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight)
```

What that does is take the whole screen height of the moitor, then subtracts the value of the height of the tabs, taskbar etc. This works fine and dandy... *unless* you open the inspector.

So.... how do you calculate the height of the inspector or is there any other way to calculate *the biggest possible height of the document*. (Would be very convenient if it works for both chrome and firefox.)

Comment: _"biggest possible height of the document"_ - do you mean the viewport/window, or the document itself? The document can be arbitrarily high. E.g. `document.body.style.height = \`${Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}px\`;`

Comment: I would say, of the window.

Comment: https://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/ gives a good list of the properties and their values - [`window.outerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.outerHeight "Inconsistent.") gives the largest height value

Comment: Thanks! I got it! what I needed was window.screen.availHeight

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to evolutionxbox, I got the answer! If anyone want's the answer, it's window.screen.availHeight

Edit: This works on my windows computer, but not on my windows laptop :| So I guess I'll still be waiting for answers.